# Importing using Datloader without creating duplicates

Tags: data-loader, duplicate-management

Is there a way to import into Salesforce without creating Duplicate Accounts or Contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove duplicates directly from Data Loader. But you can do some workaround on this and install DupeBlocker app (on AppExchange) and configure it to prevent duplicate records from being inserted in SF.

Also you may clear your Excel file with 'Remove Duplicate Records' function before importing it through Data Loader.